# Association with JSON field in Shopware6 entity definition

Tags: associations, shopware6

I have an entity with category_ids as json field, I want to add an association to category entity to get the names of the categories
How to do that

This is my entity definition,This **ManyToManyAssociationField** is not working

```
protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
            (new StringField('group_name','group_name')),
            (new JsonField('category_ids', 'category_ids'))->addFlags(new Required()),
            (new FkField('shipping_method_id', 'shipping_method_id', ShippingMethodDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Required()),
            (new CreatedAtField()),
            (new UpdatedAtField()),
            (new ManyToOneAssociationField('shippingMethod', 'shipping_method_id', ShippingMethodDefinition::class)),
            new ManyToManyAssociationField('category', CategoryDefinition::class, GroupDefinition::class, 'category_ids', 'id'),
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associations within JSON fields are generally not supported. Instead, you need to create a mapping table and a `MappingEntityDefinition` to handle the association. On how to do that exactly, take a look at [the docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-data-associations.html#many-to-many-associations).

If for whatever reason (e.g. faster query performance without a table scan on the mapping table), you additionally need the Ids of the associated entities in a JSON field, you can add an additional `ManyToManyIdField` and an Indexer that fills this field. Take a look [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-data-indexer.html#adding-data-indexer) on how to do that. As an example take a look at the [`SalesChannelIndexer`](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/trunk/src/Core/System/SalesChannel/DataAbstractionLayer/SalesChannelIndexer.php) from the core, that populates the `paymentMethodIds` field for every sales channel.

Answer (score 0):

ManyToMany associations won't work with a `JsonField`, you need a `MappingEntityDefinition` for that, so an additional database table.
Please take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-data-associations.html#many-to-many-associations)

You could add an additional field with a `Runtime` flag and set the data via event subscriber, if you want to stick with your JsonField